# Error al conectar a una dase de datos local con pymysql

Tags: python, sql-server, localhost, pymysql

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión a una base de datos hospedada en mi Pc (localhost) usando pymysql, para lo cual creé una clase como la siguiente

```
import pymysql

class DataBase():
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn= pymysql.connect(
      host='localhost',
      user='usuario',
      password='',
      port=49339,
      db='db'
    )
    
    self.cur= self.conn.cursor()
    print("Conectado")
```

pero al ejecutar el metodo para conectarme recibo el error "**ConnectionResetError [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto**" (El error toma un tiempo en presentarse, luego de ejecutar el comando recibo el mensaje después de unos 12-15 segundos)

Desde el administrador del Sql Server veo que está corriendo normalmente, y no tengo otra conexión activa hacía esa BD, he revisado el puerto y también es el correcto. No sé qué puede ser y agradecería cualquier luz al respecto. Gracias

Comment: mmm... puede ser el firewall

Comment: Como dice Christian, probaste con desactivar el firewall y conectarte a la base de datos? Igual te advierto, no es seguro que desactives el firewall cada vez que requieras conectarte a la base de datos.